# How to pick source from build dir if available otherwise use source dir?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

is there a way to force CMAKE pick sources form current build folder if file(s) is available otherwise take it from the source directory?

My project has following structure:

```
ROOT/lib/a.cpp
    /BUILD
```

the BUILD folder is where I run `cmake ..`. I've got an optional custom target which generates a source `BUILD/lib/a.cpp` file: `cmake generate`.

I'd like to build a library in `ROOT/lib` that automatically picks up the generated source file `BUILD/lib/a.cpp` in case it exists otherwise use `ROOT/lib/a.cpp`.

The library is generated with `ROOT/lib/CMakeLists.txt` in the following way:

```
add_library(test a.cpp)
```

(the custom rule is omitted).

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the full path to generated file:

```
add_library(test ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a.cpp)
```

and if file doesn't exists, your custom command will be executed to generate it.
make sure that generated file produced by `add_custom_command()` and not by `add_custom_target()`.